# a javascript error occurred in the main process, Unity hub

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10

After I installed Unity hub and tried to Launch it in Windows 10 ,  "a javascript error occurred in the main process" appeared.

[image]

Anyone encountered the same error? How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts on your PC? `Access is denied` sounds like UnityHub is trying to read/write something in the AppData of another user?

Comment: No, there is only one account and I have also tried to run it as  administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me too (still not solved). I have an user and an admin account (the originary one) in Windows 10 (Professional).
At first I installed Unity Hub in the user account (as administrator) and this error came out.
I tried to remove  Unity Hub and to reinstall in the "admin" account. Now I can use Unity Hub in the admin account but it still give the error in the user account.